# Job for Export Data From SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

I want to create a job with a specific query to export some date from SQL Server to  Oracle. How can I schedule this? 
Thank you!

Comment: That's a job for SSIS, not SSMS. SSMS itself does have an Import/Export wizard that essentially generates SSIS packages. This means that you can save and schedule those packages with SQL Server Agent, or edit them with SSDT to create complex transformations. Right click on a database and select `Tasks > Export Data` or `Import Data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you move forward with implementing this will depend on a variety of factors, but the following steps outline this process at a high level.  Of course, you'll want to choose the configurations that best suite your specific environment and business needs.

- Create an SSIS package with an OLE DB Connection Manager to SQL
  Server
- Add a Connection Manager for Oracle.  Some options are the Microsoft
  ODBC driver for Oracle or OLE DB Provider for Oracle.  You can here
  more about setting up connections [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/integration-services-ssis-connections?view=sql-server-2017).
- After the connections are configured, you'll want to create
  components to export the data, likely using a Data Flow Task (or
  multiple).  How this is setup will vary greatly depending on the business needs.  You can use the query mentioned in your question for the SQL command in the OLE DB source to SQL Server.  I'd also recommend using stored procedures as opposed to static queries.
- After the package is complete, you can add it as a job in SQL Agent
  and schedule it to run at the desired frequency.  ***Make sure that the
  account the job runs under has the necessary permissions***,
  including on both the SQL Server and Oracle objects involved.
- This is not required, but installing the SSIS catalog, deploying the projects there, and
  running them from this instead of the file system will offer many
  benefits.  This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-2017) contains
  more information on SSISDB (the catalog).

Comment: Great! Thank you!